# How to encrypt and decrypt specific language in python

Tags: python

I'm learning how to 'encrypt' and 'decrypt' the message in python, so far only the English message can successfully decrypt from alphabet list, However if i try to type the specific language message for example こんにちは after the result is same as the encrypt language, I have try using uft-8 and utf8 to encrypt, I can get the garbled from the alphabet list but if i try to decrypt it the end result is not as same as the encrypt message  I want.

```py
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]


def casear(start_text, shift_number, cipher_direction):
    
    end_text = ""
    
    if cipher_direction == "d":
        shift_number *= -1
        
    for char in start_text:
        if char in alphabet:
            position = alphabet.index(char)
            new_position = position + shift_number
            end_text += alphabet[new_position]
        else:
            end_text += char
    print(f"Here is the e{cipher_direction} result:---> {end_text}: ")

final = False

while not final:
    direction = input("Enter 'e' to encrypt, Enter 'd' to decrypt: ").lower()

    text = input("Enter massage: ").lower()
    
    shift = int(input("Enter cover number: "))

    shift = shift % 26
    
    casear(start_text=text, shift_number=shift, cipher_direction=direction)    

    restart = input("Enter 'Y' continue, Enter 'e' finish: ")
    if restart == 'e':
        final = True
        print("Bye")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must convert it(the unicode string 'こんにちは') to bytes

```py
s = "こんにちは"
s_bytes = s.encode('utf8')
print(s,"=>",s_bytes)
```

then you need to shift each byte

```py
def shift3(s_bytes):
    for b in s_bytes:
        b += 3
        if b > 255: # wrap if too big for 1 byte
           b = b - 255
        yield b # iterators make it easier to reason imho

encrypted_bytes = bytes(list(shift3(s_bytes)))
print("ENCRYPTED:",encrypted_bytes) # probably you should not try to decode these
```

then to reverse it you just ... well reverse it

```
def unshift3(encrypted_bytes):
    for b in encrypted_bytes:
        b -= 3 # reverse it
        if b < 0:
           b = 255 + b # wrap it
        yield b

decrypted_bytes = bytes(list(unshift3(encrypted_bytes)))
print("SAME?",decrypted_bytes == s_bytes) # yup!
print(decrypted_bytes.decode("utf8")) # back to unicode sir
```